# How to only log ERRORs in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I only want to log errors in my spring boot application. This is what I have in my `application.properties` file:

```
logging.level.com.test.login=ERROR
```

However, that seems to only catch errors in **my** application. Is there a way to set it globally for everything, so I only see errors printed to my console, and nothing else? Now it prints tons of INFO statement:

[image]

Comment: `logging.level.root=ERROR`

Comment: @Compass thanks, why don't you add that as an answer with a link to docs and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

```
logging.level.root=ERROR
logging.level.org.foo.bar.baz=INFO
```

If you are using YAML, you can use the same basic layout for root, but for package-level, just write out the entire package in a single line rather than using tree format.

```
logging:
  level:
    root: ERROR
    org.foo.bar.baz: INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this property

```
logging.level.root=INFO,ERROR,DEBUG
```

Comment: does not work..